# What happens when there is uniform convergence on an unspecified set?

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, uniform-convergence

Let $\{f_n\}$ define a sequence functions between metric spaces. I know what it means to say that

"$f_n$ converges uniformly on some set $U$.".

However, what if no set is specified, what does the sentence

"$f_n$ converges uniformly."

tell us about where $f_n$ converges uniformly? When no subset is specified; does that mean it converges uniformly on all of $X$? Or does it just mean that there exist some open set on which it converges uniformly?

Comment: for a sequence of $\mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ functions  say there are 3 types of uniform convergence : on $\mathbb{R}$ (as in $f_n(x) = \frac{\sin(nx)}{n}$), on every compacts (i.e. on every fixed interval $[a,b]$, as in $f_n(x) = \sum_{k=0}^n \frac{x^k}{k!}$ converging to $e^x$) and on every compacts of some open (as in $f_n(x) = x^n$, the open being $]-1,1[$, and it converges uniformly on every fixed $[a,b] \subset ]-1,1[$)

Comment: Given no other context, the most natural interpretation would be "uniformly on all of $X$".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unless there is some context surrounding the question, allowing you to deduce $U$, I would take for $U$ the intersection of the domains of definition of $f_n$. Since usually they all have the same domain $X$ (which in this case seems to be one and the same metric space), I would say that your problem is about the convergence in the $\sup$ norm on $X$.

Comment: Although this is in the context of metric spaces, so "sup norm" may be a bit of a misnomer.  How about "convergence in the partial metric $d(f,g) = \sup\{d(f(x),g(x)) : x \in X\}$"?

Comment: @ErickWong: Yes, that one is better, thank you. I was thinking about bounded functions, which is needlessly restrictive.